# Creating test-suite with pytest in py file

Tags: python, pytest, test-suite

I have two tests created with pytest: **Test1** and **Test2**.
I would like to create method which would start whose two tests. I know that i can do it with cmd, but i prefer py file. 
In unittest there are testloader and testsuite methods:

```
t1 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Test1)
t2 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Test2)
test_suite = unittest.TestSuite([t1, t2])
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(test_suite)
```

I need same thing, but for py test

Comment: In pytest it's going to be easier to just [add markers](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html), and run the marked tests with `-m`.

Comment: Okay, i marked my both tests 
@pytest.mark.test_suite
How can i call this suite from py file?
Not from console

Comment: Run with `pytest -m test_suite`.

Comment: I think that we don`t understand each other. This is console command 
"pytest -m test_suite"
http://joxi.ru/l2ZOpbGHwb7jaA i am getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: [`import pytest; pytest.main(args=['-m', 'test_suite'])`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-main)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pytest.main()` at the end of the test file. You can also pass arguments as list: `pytest.main(['-x', 'mytestdir']).

Documentation: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code